# Installing different versions from AppCenter

Tags: ios, appcenter

There is:

Version 1.1.1 in AppCenter.ms

There is also:

Version 1.1.2 in AppCenter.ms

I install first 1.1.1, I login there, then I do some stuffs (to create some data to be locally saved)

Then I go to AppCenter, and install (with the logic of update) 1.1.2.

It deletes the version 1.1.1 completely and installs 1.1.2 due to that fact it logs you out and removes also locally saved (but not backed up) data.

When you do the same thing using TestFlight, then it does not do such kind of thing, because when you install X.X.1 first, then you install X.X.2 from Testflight, it accepts it as an update. It also does not do it when you rebuild the project by changing the version & buildnumber using XCode.

Is there any way to achieve the behaviour of testflight with appcenter as well?